# Integrating a harmonic function over a tetrahedron

Tags: quadrature

Say I have a function $f : \mathbf{R}^3 \to \mathbf{R}$ that I wish to integrate over a tetrahedron $T \subset \mathbf{R}^3$.  If $f$ was arbitrary, Gauss quadrature would be a good solution, but I happen to know that $f$ is harmonic.  How much can Gauss quadrature be accelerated using this information?

For example, if $T$ was instead a sphere, evaluating $f$ once at the center of the sphere gives the exact answer by the mean value property.

A search turned up the following paper, which is interesting but generalizes the sphere case in a different direction (to polyharmonic instead of away from spheres):

[Bojanov and Dimitrov, Gaussian extended cubature formulae for polyharmonic functions](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.105.4125)

Answer (score 1):

I found something that might be interesting.
http://www.math.kth.se/~gbjorn/exact.pdf

I hope this helps, 
Tom

Comment: That's an interesting paper, but it looks like it and its references only treat integrals of differential operators of harmonic functions.  Do you know if they can be used for straight integrals?

Comment: I'm wondering if introducing a quadrature formula with the so-called "Poisson kernel" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel) could help... Otherwise I know that some xfem techiques use harmonic functions to enrich the FE space, and therefore should use specific quadrature methods for integrating the variational forms (?).